# ViewNavigator Fails on Traversal Back to Category

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, notesview

I'm getting an interesting error in some code that is near identical (at least in structure) to code I have working, elsewhere. I'm getting a "Notes error: Entry not found in index " error, and it occurs in the line of my *ViewNavigator.getNext(ViewEntry)* in a while loop. I feel like I'm missing something obvious on this one, so hopefully someone can spot it (I'm going batty from just staring at it).

[Update]
Jesse's note on setting autoUpdate to false did the trick. It seems to relate back to [this tech note from 2002](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21096729), as my loop does save to another document (same DB, different View) during this loop. I succeeded by placing `vw.setAutoUpdate(false);` immediately after I defined my handle on the View.
[/Update]

I'm walking a single-category View (by reference field value from each Document in the View) to summarize some information from the grouped Documents. After enabling debug, I found that the error occurs on my traversal from the last Document (ViewEntry of a Doc) in the first category back to a category (ViewEntry).

Here's a stripped down version of my code (//... denotes removed lines for clarity):

```java
View vw = db.getView("<ViewName>");
ViewNavigator nav = vw.createViewNav();
ViewEntry first = nav.getFirst();
String unid = "";
while(first != null){
  if(first.isCategory()){
    if(!unid.isEmpty()){
      //summarize the info and save it back to the category-relevant doc
      Document myDoc = db.getDocumentByUNID(unid);
      //doing my thing
      boolean success = myDoc.save(true, false);
      myDoc.recycle();
    }
    unid = "";
  }
  if(first.isDocument()){
    Vector<?> colVals = first.getColumnValues();
    if(unid.isEmpty()){
      //reset temp aggregation vars back to initial value (e.g.- 0)
      //...
      unid = (String) colVals.get(5); // the value of the category-relevant UNID
    }else{
      //doing the aggregation of summary values with the temp vars established before and handled after
      //...
      //perform aggregation from colVals with temp vars
    }
    session.recycle(colVals);
  }
  ViewEntry tmp = nav.getNext(first); //this is the line that fails!! only if it's the next category, which there is one
  first.recycle();
  first = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting view.setAutoUpdate(false) should clear it up, probably because of the document save in there.

I've found it to be a good policy to set this all the time after fetching a view (I believe ODA does it automatically in Khan mode). It also then lets you set nav.setBufferMaxEntries(400), which improves lengthy view navigation.

Comment: Sounds like another good reason to use the OpenNTF Domino API.